# How to set properties used in New-ProtectionAlert filter?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

The Powershell New-ProtectionAlert cmdlet provides a filter parameter that allows you to define more granular conditions for when your alert should be raised.

- My question is how/where are the 'filterable properties' defined so you can filter on them?

I am working on an Exchange Online connector that I want to raise an alert when a violation is detected.

- I have created an M365 Alert Policy that will trigger if the Mail:IsThreat property is $true
- However, how/where do I set that property in my connector or the message returned to Exchange?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The references in the Exchange for PowerShell docs are a bit convoluted, but the full list is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/filter-properties?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Thanks but I've already read that page. Also the 'Note' at the top of the page says other cmdlets (like the New-ProtectionAlert one I want to use) support filterable properties but are different to these user and group properties. What I really need to know is where the properties get defined and by what, in particular the Mail properties used by New-ProtectionAlert filter. Thanks!